# How can this recursive function return true?

Tags: c#, function, recursion

This is my recursive function :

```
public bool controllaSelezioneSottopagina(KPage k_oPaginaAttuale, KPage k_oPaginaSuperiore)
{
    foreach (KPage k_oSottoPagina in k_oPaginaSuperiore.SottoPagine)
    {
        if (k_oSottoPagina.ID == k_oPaginaAttuale.ID)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (k_oSottoPagina.SottoPagine.Count != 0)
            {
                controllaSelezioneSottopagina(k_oPaginaAttuale, k_oSottoPagina);
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

I aspect, from where I call it, to get ALWAYS false (the `return false` at the end of the function, will be the last result that will be returned, EVER).

In fact, sometimes it returns true.

How it is possible? Tried debugging... but I can't find out the mistake...

Comment: Could you post the definition of the `KPage` class, and show how you are calling `controllaSelezioneSottopagina` to cause the false return value?

Comment: You need to `return` the recursive call.

Comment: maybe.. for first k_oSottoPagina the ` if (k_oSottoPagina.ID == k_oPaginaAttuale.ID)` is true?

Comment: @Darren Young : yes, but will return to the point where I call it. Not from to the first call.

Comment: btw, my 0.02$ - try to name properties/types/variables in english, or at least translate them before posting to SO, it is hard for me to understand what is probably going on.

Comment: @Yossarian : of course not :) It returns `true` after some recursion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call the function once, then it loops, and either returns true or calls itself recussively. It will only return false if it loops through all elements and the condition (k_oSottoPagina.ID == k_oPaginaAttuale.ID) is never met.

Now assume that this condition is actually met in the first level (there was no recursion made yet or all recursive call return).

You call the function once, it loops and for example on the first test this condition is true. Then you will see a return value 'true'

Answer (score 1):

I think this could happen only in first iteration. I mean that only first comparison may result in returning true. Recursive call would never happen then.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying this code block will never be true in the first call to the function (the first time through the loop)?

```
k_oSottoPagina.ID == k_oPaginaAttuale.ID
```

Since you don't return the result of the recursive call, your function either blows the stack, returns true through the first loop at some point, or finishes the loop and returns false.

Comment: Not quite, it will only return true if the IDs match on the first call, because he doesn't return the result of his recursive call, if he ever makes a recursive call (from his structure) it will return false.

Comment: @James Michael Hare : checked again with the debugger. First call don't match the IDs. So, the recursion start. Than, I get true :O That's why I opened this topic...

Comment: As a few people have mentioned, you should return the result of the recursive call, otherwise any time the above test matches inside the original loop will return true.

Answer (score 0):

another alternative to not printing incorrect false in the cases where it does go in the loop is

```
public bool controllaSelezioneSottopagina(KPage k_oPaginaAttuale, KPage k_oPaginaSuperiore)
{
    foreach (KPage k_oSottoPagina in k_oPaginaSuperiore.SottoPagine)
    {
        if (k_oSottoPagina.ID == k_oPaginaAttuale.ID)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            if (k_oSottoPagina.SottoPagine.Count != 0)
            {
                if(controllaSelezioneSottopagina(k_oPaginaAttuale, k_oSottoPagina))
                {
                  return true;
                 }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```